# SQL. Check if 2 lists are intersects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to check if result of sub-query intersects with list of numbers.

I'm trying to use this query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt WHERE 
   EXISTS (
     (SELECT at.id FROM another_table at where at.some_id = mt.id) 
       INTERSECT 
     (1,2,3,4)
   )
```

The `(1, 2, 3, 4)` will be substituted at runtime by application.

But I'm getting error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
```

How I can solve this problem?
I'm using `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: Try `VALUES ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VALUE-lists:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt
WHERE 
   EXISTS (
     (SELECT at.id FROM another_table at where at.some_id = mt.id) 
       INTERSECT 
     VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
   );
```

if it's a number range you could use the function `generate_series` also:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt
WHERE 
   EXISTS (
     (SELECT at.id FROM another_table at where at.some_id = mt.id) 
       INTERSECT 
     SELECT generate_series(1,4)
   );
```

The `INTERSECT` is not necessary though. You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt
WHERE 
   EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 FROM another_table at where at.some_id = mt.id AND at.id IN (1,2,3,4));
```

or again, if it's a range:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt
WHERE 
   EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 FROM another_table at where at.some_id = mt.id AND at.id BETWEEN 1 AND 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `VALUES` to generate a "constant table" consumed by `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt WHERE 
   EXISTS (
     (SELECT at.id FROM another_table at where at.some_id = mt.id) 
       INTERSECT VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
   )
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/83aec/5)